# Tensorflow saver.save() not working properly

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Calling saver.save() saves four files on google colab but on my local I am just getting a checkpoint file. (using macOS High Sierra)

```
def train(model,model_dir,batch_szie,tr_x,tr_y,val_x,val_y,lr_rate):
saver = tf.train.Saver()
epoch = 0
max_epoch = 300
print ("starting training")
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  while epoch < max_epoch:
    for br_x,br_y in shuffle_batch(tr_x,tr_y,batch_size):
      sess.run(model.opt,feed_dict={model.inputs:br_x,model.outputs:br_y,model.is_training:True,model.lr_rate:lr_rate})  

    epoch = epoch + 1
  saver.save(sess,model_dir,write_meta_graph=True)
  print ('completed training, model saved')
```

This is how I call the training function. the custom_dnn() function creates an object of a custom class and then train function is called. The model is trained properly, I have visualised the training graph but on saving, only a checkpoint file is saved on my local.

```
model_dir = "/Users/proj/model/"
batch_size = 50
lr_rate = 0.001
tf.reset_default_graph()
model_sub1 = custom_dnn()
train(model_sub1,model_dir,batch_size,tr_x,tr_y,val_x,val_y,lr_rate)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @i_th I haven't yet solved this. Please help.

Comment: Try to change the `saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=n)` where `n` the number of your files which is in your case 4 `saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4)`